# How will you inform the server about auto renewal after deleting the app in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, auto-renewing

Before marking this question as duplicate i want to understand one thing. This scenario has been argued many times here, but i still have few doubts?

1. We have a auto renewal concept in our app, I know that once purchase done receipt will be generated. Using Apple API we can validate the receipt, My question is what would be the case if user didnt open the app for a long time? How will i send the receipt verification to my server to maintain the subscription status?
2. What if user once finishing the auto renewal later he deleted the app and installed it in new device? How will i track the subscription status without opening the app?
3. Is there any API we can use directly to question the apple server about the transaction details ?

I tried my hard to understand the things, but still am logging in this. If someone have idea just help me to understand it!! Thanks in advance.